# ffmpeg - How to determine if -movflags faststart is enabled? PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4, qt-faststart

While I am able to encode an mp4 file which I can play on my local windows machine, I am having trouble encoding files to mp4 which are readable when streaming by safari, etc.

After a bit of reading, I believe my issue is that I must move the metadata from the end of the file to the beginning in order for the converted mp4 files to  be streamable.

To that end, I am trying to find out if the build of ffmpeg that I am currently using is able to use the -movflags faststart option through php - as my current outputted mp4 files are not working when streamed online.

This is the way I am now echoing the -help, -formats, -codecs, but I am not seeing anything about -movflags faststart in any of the lists:

```
exec($ffmpegPath." -help", $codecArr);
for($ii=0;$ii<count($codecArr);$ii++){
    echo $codecArr[$ii].'</br>';
}
```

Is there a similar method of determining if -movflags fastart is available to my ffmpeg build?  Any other way?  Should it be listed with any of the previously suggested commands? -help/-formats?

Can someone that knows it is enabled in their version of ffmpeg check to see if it is listed under -help or -formats, etc.?

TIA.

EDIT: COMPLETE CONSOLE OUTPUT FOR BOTH THE CONVERSION COMMAND AND -MOVFLAGS COMMAND BELOW:

COMMAND:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\vidtests\Wildlife.wmv -s 640x480 C:\vidtests\Wildlife.mp4
```

OUTPUT:

```
ffmpeg version N-54207-ge59fb3f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 25 2013 21:55:00 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 37.101 / 52. 37.101
  libavcodec     55. 17.100 / 55. 17.100
  libavformat    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 77.101 /  3. 77.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[asf @ 00000000002ed760] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider
 increasing probesize
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from 'C:\vidtests\Wildlife.wmv'
:
  Metadata:
    SfOriginalFPS   : 299700
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.6001.7000
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    comment         : Footage: Small World Productions, Inc; Tourism New Zealand
 | Producer: Gary F. Spradling | Music: Steve Ball
    title           : Wildlife in HD
    copyright       : ┬⌐ 2008 Microsoft Corporation
    IsVBR           : 0
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: AP@L3
  Duration: 00:00:30.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6977 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp
, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vc1 (Advanced) (WVC1 / 0x31435657), yuv420p, 1280x7
20, 5942 kb/s, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64

[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] 264 - core 133 r2334 a3ac64b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\vidtests\Wildlife.mp4':

  Metadata:
    SfOriginalFPS   : 299700
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.6001.7000
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    comment         : Footage: Small World Productions, Inc; Tourism New Zealand
 | Producer: Gary F. Spradling | Music: Steve Ball
    title           : Wildlife in HD
    copyright       : ┬⌐ 2008 Microsoft Corporation
    IsVBR           : 0
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: AP@L3
    encoder         : Lavf55.10.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 6
40x480, q=-1--1, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100
Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (vc1 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (wmav2 -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   53 fps= 49 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.13 bitrate=   2.9kbits/
frame=   63 fps= 40 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/
frame=   74 fps= 35 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.83 bitrate=   0.5kbits/
frame=   85 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.20 bitrate=   0.3kbits/
frame=   95 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.53 bitrate=   0.3kbits/
frame=  107 fps= 28 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.93 bitrate=   0.2kbits/
Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 00000000003ef800] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7616
, current: 7063; changing to 7617. This may result in incorrect timestamps in th
e output file.
frame=  118 fps= 28 q=29.0 size=     113kB time=00:00:02.30 bitrate= 402.6kbits/
frame=  129 fps= 26 q=29.0 size=     219kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate= 670.7kbits/
frame=  141 fps= 26 q=29.0 size=     264kB time=00:00:03.06 bitrate= 704.2kbits/
frame=  152 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=     328kB time=00:00:03.43 bitrate= 782.2kbits/
frame=  163 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=     431kB time=00:00:03.80 bitrate= 928.1kbits/
frame=  174 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=     568kB time=00:00:04.17 bitrate=1116.3kbits/
frame=  190 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=     781kB time=00:00:04.70 bitrate=1359.9kbits/
frame=  204 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1006kB time=00:00:05.17 bitrate=1593.1kbits/
frame=  218 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1058kB time=00:00:05.63 bitrate=1536.8kbits/
frame=  229 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1093kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate=1490.9kbits/
frame=  239 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    1118kB time=00:00:06.33 bitrate=1444.4kbits/
frame=  251 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    1150kB time=00:00:06.74 bitrate=1397.9kbits/
frame=  265 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    1234kB time=00:00:07.20 bitrate=1402.3kbits/
frame=  278 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1332kB time=00:00:07.64 bitrate=1428.3kbits/
frame=  294 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1403kB time=00:00:08.17 bitrate=1405.7kbits/
frame=  308 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1547kB time=00:00:08.64 bitrate=1466.4kbits/
frame=  323 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1595kB time=00:00:09.14 bitrate=1429.5kbits/
frame=  337 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1702kB time=00:00:09.60 bitrate=1450.7kbits/
frame=  351 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1755kB time=00:00:10.07 bitrate=1427.1kbits/
frame=  365 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1820kB time=00:00:10.54 bitrate=1414.1kbits/
frame=  381 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1852kB time=00:00:11.07 bitrate=1369.6kbits/
frame=  396 fps= 26 q=29.0 size=    1893kB time=00:00:11.57 bitrate=1339.5kbits/
frame=  409 fps= 26 q=29.0 size=    1923kB time=00:00:12.01 bitrate=1311.8kbits/
frame=  421 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1967kB time=00:00:12.41 bitrate=1298.3kbits/
frame=  434 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1998kB time=00:00:12.84 bitrate=1274.0kbits/
frame=  445 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2018kB time=00:00:13.21 bitrate=1251.3kbits/
frame=  458 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:13.64 bitrate=1229.5kbits/
frame=  471 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2067kB time=00:00:14.08 bitrate=1202.3kbits/
frame=  484 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2189kB time=00:00:14.51 bitrate=1235.5kbits/
frame=  497 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2260kB time=00:00:14.94 bitrate=1238.3kbits/
frame=  509 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2311kB time=00:00:15.34 bitrate=1233.3kbits/
frame=  523 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2429kB time=00:00:15.81 bitrate=1258.1kbits/
frame=  535 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2541kB time=00:00:16.21 bitrate=1283.5kbits/
frame=  548 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2718kB time=00:00:16.64 bitrate=1337.5kbits/
frame=  560 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2845kB time=00:00:17.05 bitrate=1367.1kbits/
frame=  571 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    2965kB time=00:00:17.41 bitrate=1394.6kbits/
frame=  580 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    3025kB time=00:00:17.71 bitrate=1398.7kbits/
frame=  588 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    3098kB time=00:00:17.98 bitrate=1411.1kbits/
frame=  597 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    3183kB time=00:00:18.28 bitrate=1426.1kbits/
frame=  606 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    3279kB time=00:00:18.58 bitrate=1445.2kbits/
frame=  616 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    3441kB time=00:00:18.91 bitrate=1489.9kbits/
frame=  626 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    3650kB time=00:00:19.25 bitrate=1553.0kbits/
frame=  638 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    3826kB time=00:00:19.65 bitrate=1594.7kbits/
frame=  649 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    3950kB time=00:00:20.02 bitrate=1616.3kbits/
frame=  660 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    4067kB time=00:00:20.38 bitrate=1634.1kbits/
frame=  669 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    4121kB time=00:00:20.68 bitrate=1631.8kbits/
frame=  682 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    4274kB time=00:00:21.12 bitrate=1657.9kbits/
frame=  696 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    4446kB time=00:00:21.58 bitrate=1687.1kbits/
frame=  709 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    4590kB time=00:00:22.02 bitrate=1707.3kbits/
frame=  719 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    4772kB time=00:00:22.35 bitrate=1748.5kbits/
frame=  732 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    4852kB time=00:00:22.78 bitrate=1744.3kbits/
frame=  744 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    4973kB time=00:00:23.18 bitrate=1756.9kbits/
frame=  756 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5099kB time=00:00:23.59 bitrate=1770.8kbits/
frame=  768 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5149kB time=00:00:23.99 bitrate=1758.4kbits/
frame=  780 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5227kB time=00:00:24.39 bitrate=1755.7kbits/
frame=  797 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5377kB time=00:00:24.95 bitrate=1765.0kbits/
frame=  813 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5507kB time=00:00:25.49 bitrate=1769.5kbits/
frame=  828 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5634kB time=00:00:25.99 bitrate=1775.5kbits/
frame=  843 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5701kB time=00:00:26.49 bitrate=1762.9kbits/
frame=  859 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5830kB time=00:00:27.02 bitrate=1767.0kbits/
frame=  872 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    5926kB time=00:00:27.46 bitrate=1767.7kbits/
frame=  888 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    6014kB time=00:00:27.99 bitrate=1759.7kbits/
frame=  900 fps= 24 q=29.0 size=    6332kB time=00:00:28.39 bitrate=1826.9kbits/
frame=  901 fps= 24 q=-1.0 Lsize=    6717kB time=00:00:30.10 bitrate=1828.0kbits
/s
video:6211kB audio:472kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.513217%

[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] frame I:8     Avg QP:21.77  size: 39744
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] frame P:433   Avg QP:25.69  size: 11490
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] frame B:460   Avg QP:29.25  size:  2319
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] consecutive B-frames:  5.4% 78.6%  2.7% 13.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] mb I  I16..4: 21.8% 48.8% 29.5%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] mb P  I16..4:  0.7%  4.0%  1.3%  P16..4: 37.1% 22.2
% 15.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:19.2%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.5%  0.2%  B16..8: 43.5%  7.0
%  2.1%  direct: 2.2%  skip:44.5%  L0:36.4% L1:52.7% BI:10.9%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] 8x8 transform intra:62.8% inter:56.2%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 74.2% 78.8% 44.0% inter: 2
3.6% 14.5% 1.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] i16 v,h,dc,p: 48% 24%  9% 20%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 17% 15%  7%  8%
11%  8% 10%  8%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 17% 15%  7% 10%
11%  8%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] i8c dc,h,v,p: 53% 21% 18%  7%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.7% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] ref P L0: 62.4% 19.0% 12.0%  6.6%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] ref B L0: 90.5%  8.9%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] ref B L1: 97.9%  2.1%
[libx264 @ 00000000002e6980] kb/s:1692.37
```

AND THE –MOVFLAGS COMMAND:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\vidtests\Wildlife.mp4 -movflags faststart C:\vidtests\Wildlife_fs.mp4
```

AND THE –MOVFLAGS OUTPUT

```
ffmpeg version N-54207-ge59fb3f Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 25 2013 21:55:00 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 37.101 / 52. 37.101
  libavcodec     55. 17.100 / 55. 17.100
  libavformat    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavdevice    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavfilter     3. 77.101 /  3. 77.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\vidtests\Wildlife.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Wildlife in HD
    encoder         : Lavf55.10.100
    comment         : Footage: Small World Productions, Inc; Tourism New Zealand
 | Producer: Gary F. Spradling | Music: Steve Ball
    copyright       : ┬⌐ 2008 Microsoft Corporation
  Duration: 00:00:30.13, start: 0.036281, bitrate: 1826 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480,
1692 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 12
8 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64

[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] 264 - core 133 r2334 a3ac64b - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC cod
ec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 r
ef=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed
_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pski
p=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 deci
mate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_
adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=2
5 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.6
0 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\vidtests\Wildlife_fs.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : Wildlife in HD
    copyright       : ┬⌐ 2008 Microsoft Corporation
    comment         : Footage: Small World Productions, Inc; Tourism New Zealand
 | Producer: Gary F. Spradling | Music: Steve Ball
    encoder         : Lavf55.10.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 6
40x480, q=-1--1, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100
Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libvo_aacenc)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   52 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=      29kB time=00:00:01.76 bitrate= 133.9kbits/
frame=   63 fps= 60 q=29.0 size=     104kB time=00:00:02.14 bitrate= 397.2kbits/
frame=   74 fps= 47 q=29.0 size=     176kB time=00:00:02.51 bitrate= 573.2kbits/
frame=   87 fps= 41 q=29.0 size=     265kB time=00:00:02.93 bitrate= 741.2kbits/
frame=  101 fps= 37 q=29.0 size=     358kB time=00:00:03.39 bitrate= 862.8kbits/
frame=  113 fps= 34 q=29.0 size=     437kB time=00:00:03.79 bitrate= 943.7kbits/
frame=  125 fps= 33 q=29.0 size=     520kB time=00:00:04.20 bitrate=1012.2kbits/
frame=  138 fps= 32 q=29.0 size=     606kB time=00:00:04.64 bitrate=1069.8kbits/
frame=  151 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=     696kB time=00:00:05.06 bitrate=1124.3kbits/
frame=  163 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     780kB time=00:00:05.47 bitrate=1166.4kbits/
frame=  176 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     919kB time=00:00:05.90 bitrate=1273.9kbits/
frame=  196 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=     994kB time=00:00:06.57 bitrate=1237.4kbits/
frame=  213 fps= 31 q=29.0 size=    1097kB time=00:00:07.13 bitrate=1258.8kbits/
frame=  225 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1204kB time=00:00:07.53 bitrate=1309.8kbits/
frame=  236 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1323kB time=00:00:07.91 bitrate=1369.4kbits/
frame=  249 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    1451kB time=00:00:08.34 bitrate=1424.6kbits/
frame=  263 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    1574kB time=00:00:08.82 bitrate=1461.3kbits/
frame=  278 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    1610kB time=00:00:09.30 bitrate=1416.9kbits/
frame=  296 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1655kB time=00:00:09.91 bitrate=1368.0kbits/
frame=  313 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1697kB time=00:00:10.48 bitrate=1326.4kbits/
frame=  330 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1737kB time=00:00:11.05 bitrate=1286.5kbits/
frame=  345 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1776kB time=00:00:11.54 bitrate=1260.4kbits/
frame=  361 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1813kB time=00:00:12.07 bitrate=1230.3kbits/
frame=  377 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1847kB time=00:00:12.59 bitrate=1201.4kbits/
frame=  395 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1880kB time=00:00:13.22 bitrate=1165.0kbits/
frame=  410 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    1993kB time=00:00:13.72 bitrate=1190.2kbits/
frame=  424 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2080kB time=00:00:14.18 bitrate=1201.4kbits/
frame=  439 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2166kB time=00:00:14.67 bitrate=1209.4kbits/
frame=  455 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2262kB time=00:00:15.21 bitrate=1217.5kbits/
frame=  469 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2341kB time=00:00:15.68 bitrate=1223.0kbits/
frame=  484 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2430kB time=00:00:16.19 bitrate=1229.1kbits/
frame=  500 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2523kB time=00:00:16.71 bitrate=1236.3kbits/
frame=  515 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2607kB time=00:00:17.21 bitrate=1240.4kbits/
frame=  531 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2681kB time=00:00:17.73 bitrate=1238.2kbits/
frame=  546 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2758kB time=00:00:18.24 bitrate=1238.2kbits/
frame=  561 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2824kB time=00:00:18.75 bitrate=1233.4kbits/
frame=  576 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=    2955kB time=00:00:19.25 bitrate=1256.8kbits/
frame=  586 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    3061kB time=00:00:19.59 bitrate=1279.6kbits/
frame=  598 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    3217kB time=00:00:19.99 bitrate=1318.4kbits/
frame=  610 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    3354kB time=00:00:20.39 bitrate=1347.2kbits/
frame=  622 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    3483kB time=00:00:20.78 bitrate=1372.6kbits/
frame=  634 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    3593kB time=00:00:21.19 bitrate=1388.6kbits/
frame=  648 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    3708kB time=00:00:21.66 bitrate=1402.3kbits/
frame=  661 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    3811kB time=00:00:22.08 bitrate=1413.5kbits/
frame=  674 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    3978kB time=00:00:22.53 bitrate=1446.3kbits/
frame=  690 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    4133kB time=00:00:23.05 bitrate=1468.4kbits/
frame=  706 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    4263kB time=00:00:23.58 bitrate=1480.4kbits/
frame=  721 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    4391kB time=00:00:24.08 bitrate=1493.8kbits/
frame=  735 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    4524kB time=00:00:24.55 bitrate=1509.4kbits/
frame=  748 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    4661kB time=00:00:24.98 bitrate=1528.2kbits/
frame=  763 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    4835kB time=00:00:25.50 bitrate=1553.1kbits/
frame=  778 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    4993kB time=00:00:25.99 bitrate=1573.6kbits/
frame=  795 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    5149kB time=00:00:26.56 bitrate=1588.1kbits/
frame=  814 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    5258kB time=00:00:27.18 bitrate=1584.4kbits/
frame=  833 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    5368kB time=00:00:27.82 bitrate=1580.2kbits/
frame=  851 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    5469kB time=00:00:28.43 bitrate=1575.9kbits/
frame=  870 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    5567kB time=00:00:29.05 bitrate=1569.5kbits/
frame=  889 fps= 29 q=29.0 size=    5688kB time=00:00:29.70 bitrate=1568.4kbits/
Starting second pass: moving header on top of the file
frame=  902 fps= 28 q=-1.0 Lsize=    6109kB time=00:00:30.14 bitrate=1659.8kbits
/s dup=1 drop=0
video:5602kB audio:472kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.566600%

[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] frame I:8     Avg QP:20.52  size: 39667
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] frame P:419   Avg QP:25.06  size: 10524
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] frame B:475   Avg QP:29.03  size:  2123
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] consecutive B-frames:  3.2% 79.6%  0.3% 16.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] mb I  I16..4: 20.7% 52.3% 26.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] mb P  I16..4:  0.7%  4.2%  1.1%  P16..4: 39.4% 21.4
% 13.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:19.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.9%  0.3%  B16..8: 41.8%  6.4
%  1.7%  direct: 1.7%  skip:47.1%  L0:36.4% L1:53.3% BI:10.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] 8x8 transform intra:65.7% inter:58.8%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 71.2% 76.6% 35.7% inter: 2
0.7% 13.0% 0.5%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] i16 v,h,dc,p: 48% 24%  8% 20%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 18% 15%  6%  8%
11%  8% 10%  8%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 16% 15%  7% 10%
11%  8%  8%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 22% 19%  9%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.7% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] ref P L0: 63.4% 19.7% 11.0%  5.9%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] ref B L0: 90.7%  8.7%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] ref B L1: 98.4%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0000000004360620] kb/s:1524.54
```

Comment: See `man ffmpeg-formats` or `ffmpeg -h full`. The standalone `qt-faststart` tool has been around for a while and is available in the tools directory of the ffmpeg source (`cd ~/ffmpeg/tools && make qt-faststart`), and the `faststart` option for `-movflags` was introduced in commit [a714150](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=a714150827c70f8baf2ec42dfecd9363c17e803d) on 2012-09-27.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thank you. I found a bit of info regarding moov in the list provided by the h-full command, and believe the version of ffmpeg I am currently running does have the -movflags faststart option built-in (I tried the command on a previous version and the command failed in less than a second while my current version seems to process for much longer).  In any case, the outputted mp4 file still does not play in safari/chrome but will play locally on my windows pc. I am using a pre-compiled windows build from zeranoe.com as I am not sure how to compile new versions of ffmpeg myself.

Comment: You need to show your ffmpeg command and the complete console output for the file that will not play as expected in your browsers.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: I have added the console output to my initial post.  For further info: I am able to view the video in safari if I use a direct link to the file, however, when embedded, the video will not play.  In chrome, neither the direct link / html5 embed code will work.  The same goes for android, neither the direct link nor the html5 embed code is functional.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Thanks for the scaling info, however, I am still unable to output an mp4 which is embedded/streamable in safari/chrome using ffmpeg.  I have tried 3 different ffmpeg builds and several different commands/options/etc. but to no avail.  P.S. I am able to convert to .ogg and .webM without issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32587/discussion-between-lordneckbeard-and-iiioxiii)

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623988/ffmpeg-gives-an-error-option-movflags-not-found

Comment: This is not completely relevant but you may do this with other software too.
I'm currently using [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) to add the metadata the my mp4 files.
Have a look at their --inter --dash --hint options.

Comment: will the ffmpeg team ever add an option for this ? Why the need for mp4box ?

Comment: Could the issue be with the webserver configuration and/or the headers it sends? Have you tried the file from different web servers? I have a project for which I encode videos from stills, with few options specified, using libx264 and ffmpeg 2.6, streams fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

Your command is missing a plus sign, which should give you "moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file" in the output. The correct command would be:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\vidtests\Wildlife.mp4 -movflags +faststart C:\vidtests\Wildlife_fs.mp4
```

As a rule of thumb, when not encoding/transcoding I would advise to use "-vcodec copy -acodec copy" parameters like so:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\vidtests\Wildlife.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags +faststart C:\vidtests\Wildlife_fs.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/), `AtomicParsley input.mp4 -T` .I found the way to check it in this post and it work perfect!!
Here the full soluction: https://superuser.com/questions/559372/using-ffmpeg-to-locate-moov-atom.