# ffmpeg gives an error Option movflags not found

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04, transcode

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I have used `-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov` in my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i http://filesbe.vocativ.internal.net/03/44/SN/q1/xg/xl/0344SNq1xgxl.flv \
-crf 32.0 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -aspect 4:3  -movflags frag_keyframe -vcodec \
libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -map 0:0 \
-map 0:1 -f flv -y test.flv

ffmpeg version 0.8.6-4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Apr  2 2013 17:02:36 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
[flv @ 0x10569a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'http://filesbe.vocativ.internal.net/03/44/SN/q1/xg/xl/0344SNq1xgxl.flv':
  Metadata:
    starttime       : 0
    totalduration   : 64
    totaldatarate   : 710
    bytelength      : 5674798
    canseekontime   : true
    sourcedata      : BADC23401MH1326550770698632
    purl            :
    pmsg            :
  Duration: 00:01:03.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 718 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 854x480, 590 kb/s, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
[buffer @ 0x105c600] w:854 h:480 pixfmt:yuv420p
[movie @ 0x105c440] seek_point:0 format_name:(null) file_name:/home/assetproxy/htdocs/transcoder/helper_asset/voca_scaled.png stream_index:0
[overlay @ 0x1060840] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'Parsed filter 0 movie' and the filter 'Parsed filter 1 overlay'
[scale @ 0x11d8300] w:90 h:51 fmt:rgb24 -> w:90 h:51 fmt:yuva420p flags:0x4
[overlay @ 0x1060840] main w:854 h:480 fmt:yuv420p overlay x:754 y:419 w:90 h:51 fmt:yuva420p
[overlay @ 0x1060840] main_tb:1/1000000 overlay_tb:1/25 -> tb:1/1000000 exact:1
[libx264 @ 0x1059d20] using SAR=191/255
[libx264 @ 0x1059d20] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x1059d20] profile Main, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x1059d20] 264 - core 120 r2151 a3f4407 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=0 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=0 open_gop=1 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=32.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
Option movflags not found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're not actually using ffmpeg from FFmpeg, but an old and outdated version from a fork which does not have the `-movflags` option. You will need to update your ffmpeg: you can simply [download a Linux build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) (see [detailed instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/270107/59378)), or you can follow a step-by-step [guide to compile ffmpeg on Ubuntu](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Also see:

- [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017)
- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide)

Comment: I have an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system.  I use https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide to install it.